# How to save form data in a cookie (dojo)

Tags: cookies, dojo

I have a contact form where users will enter their details like name, address, phone and so on. Now I have a checkbox (remember me) on the form.. whenever the user checks this, the information should be saved in a cookie and retrieved when the same user visits later. This is how i started..

```
<tr><td><input id="mycheck" name="mycheck" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.CheckBox" value="" checked="false" onChange="setCookie" > <label for="mycheck" >Remember me  </strong></label></td></tr>


setCookie: function () {
            cookie("UserInfo", "cookieValue", { expire: 5 });
        },
```

How do i get the cookie values (this should be whole forms data..do i need to use something like byId)...confused..any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/cookie.html

if using > 1.7 you should pull in the required module and use it by reference (as it looks like youre doing):
*NOTE is not {expire:X} but {expire***s** *:x}*

```
<script>
    require(["dojo/cookie"], function(cookie){ 
     /* set */
     cookie(cookieName, cookieValue, cookieProps);
     /* get */
     cookie(cookieName);
    });
</script>
```

You can use dojo/dom-form module to pull values and save them for a neet one-liner

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="field1" value="value1">
  <input type="text" name="field2" value="value2">
  <input type="button" name="someButton" value="someValue">
</form>
<script>
require(["dojo/dom-form", "dojo/cookie"], function(domForm, dCookie){

  dCookie(
       "formdata",
       domForm.toJson("myId"),
       {expires: 5}
  );
  // The cookie will read:  '{"field1":"value1", "field2":"value2"}'
  // Note the button was skipped. 
  // Buttons only gets sent when used as submitbutton + onclick
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks mschr...i am able to set the cookie...i am even able to get the cookie information...i am trying to store it in a array or json and then populate the form using that information..but i am unable to...any ideas?

Comment: using the above formToJson, look how the json is.. each field has a value and the key for each field is 'connected' with the name of your input. So, `var formData = dojo.cookie("formdata"); dojo.query("#myForm input").forEach(function ( inputEl) { if(inputEl.name && formData[inputEl.name]) inputEl.value = formData[inputEl.name]; });` should do the trick, looping each of your input elements and checking if a value was stored in the cookie data. cookie data is a json-string and evaluated into a js object by the eval() call

Answer (score 1):

Serialize the value to JSON then undo it when you retrieve like so:

```
//Setting the cookie to hold an array of values.
value = {my:"1",cookie:"2"};
dojo.cookie("myCookie", dojo.toJson(value), {expires: 30});
//Retrieving the cookie.
newValues = dojo.fromJson(dojo.cookie("myCookie"));
```